# How to download Embedded PDF from this website with Pdfviewer.js

Tags: pdf, javascript, embedded, file-download, iframe

with free signing-in in this website, you can view a pdf really useful for med school.

https://www.accademiamedici.it/manuale-del-neoabilitato

I cannot download it because it's embedded and uses a javascript (pdfviewer.js) and i tried to search "iframe" or "src", but I cannot find the url.

Please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the page so that we could see what you're working with?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach I use for such situations is to start poking around in the Developer tools of any browser and finding the Network tab.

Sort by file size to find the largest listing of the PDF file, as this is most likely to be the complete file without missing pages. If you don't see it, try reloading the page. From there, try these in order, from easiest to most annoying.

Method 1: If you're really lucky there will be an accessible URL for the PDF you can download directly. Just right click and open the file in a few tab, then you can save it.

Method 2: [Copy the cUrl command](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas) and pipe that to a file. In theory this may be possible from any command prompt but I've had the best luck with Linux/WSL.

Method 3: Save as HAR with content, and use something like [har-extractor](https://pypi.org/project/har-extractor/) to extract the PDF.

Comment: More recently I've started exploring JavaScript in the console, often with good results. Try something like `document.querySelector("iframe[src*='pdf']").src` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer based on how it works for me on Firefox, but similar steps should work for other browsers.

When you view a file in PDF.js, there is a toolbar on the top of the frame.  On the right side, there should be a few icons.  The one with the page and the down arrow is used to download the file.

Comment: there is no such options :(